# Nodemon watch option broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I am using *gulp-nodemon*

config directory includes only one file, server.js.

```
$.nodemon({
  script: 'config/server.js',
  watch: ['config/**/*.js']
})
.on('restart', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.livereload.changed();
   }, 1000);
 });
```

Output:

```
[gulp] [nodemon] v1.2.1
[gulp] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[gulp] [nodemon] watching: config/**/*.js
[gulp] [nodemon] starting `node config/server.js`
[gulp] [nodemon] watching 34,325 files - this might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use "--watch".
```

If i include an ignore option it fixes.

```
ignore: [
  'node_modules/**',
  'bower_components/**'
]
```

Why does nodemon watch everything even when I tell it to watch only config directory?

Also it appears from the output it only watches the config directory `[nodemon] watching: config/**/*.js`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with **[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)** itself, because I was able to reproduce it using the simple `nodemon` command :

```
> nodemon --watch app server.js
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/**/*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] watching 72,981 files - this might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use "--watch"
```

The default behavior of `nodemon` is to watch all the directories in the root of your project, 
and to ignore some directories like `node_modules`, `bower_components` or `.sass_cache`. This default `ignore` don't work actually, but was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/pull/371). Applying this fix, my output was just as expected.

```
> nodemon --watch app server.js
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/**/*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

I tested using both configurations, and even with the warning, my `nodemon` was not refreshing on a file change that is not in the specified `watched` directory, and working just as expected with no performance issue. It's more likely a false-positive warning to me.

But for now I advice you to stay with your `ignore` rule until this is merged into `nodemon` or another workaround is found.

Here some related issues about that : [#46](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon/issues/46), [#366](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/366) and [#32](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/32)